# How to make a visual skill tree in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am interested in making a UI in which the user can see and interact with a skill tree. For example by taping on one skill he would be able to see what other skills are unlocked.

Basically each skill in the tree would be a button. pressing that button would change how the tree would look like.

I've been searching and didn't find a viable approach to do this. Which widgets are recommended or packages that would enable me to do that? Something like the graph in the mockup below:

[image]

**UPDATE:
I would like to add that I'm not interested in moving the box but just changing the color of the arrows when a prior box is tag with an orange circle.**

Comment: Your question is a bit broad, it might be nice to have a picture or some sort of mock up of what you want to achieve. If my interpretation is correct the widget that you might be looking for is the ExpansionTile, check an example here. https://flutter.dev/docs/catalog/samples/expansion-tile-sample

Comment: I've added a visual

Answer (score 0):

One long way is to code all the possible orders

But you can also use keys in attempt to change the order of the widgets
Check this : 
https://medium.com/flutter/keys-what-are-they-good-for-13cb51742e7d

The third option is to look at this package: 
https://pub.dev/packages/reorderables